# Get the return values from these methods to be called into main later in the program

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to take the string input by the user and modify it in a couple of new methods to be called into main later in the program.  Currently this code isn't working and I would greatly appreciate some help getting it to work or some suggestions on the correct way to get the return values from these methods to be called into main later in the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextAnalyzer {
    /*takes the user input and counts total characters to be called later.*/
    public static int getNumOfCharacters(int textLength) { 
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String usrText = "";

        usrText = scnr.nextLine(); 
        textLength = usrText.length();

        return textLength;
    }

    /*removes all white space from string to be called later.*/
    public static String outputWithoutWhitespace(String noWhiteSpace) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String usrText = "";

        usrText = scnr.nextLine();        
        noWhiteSpace = usrText.replaceAll("\\s+","");

        return noWhiteSpace;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String usrText = "";

        System.out.print("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
        usrText = scnr.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("You entered: " + usrText);

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Number of characters: ");
        System.out.println(getNumofCharacters(usrText));

        System.out.print("String with no whitespace: ");
        System.out.println(outputWithoutWhitespace(usrText));

    }
}
```

Comment: Change your `scnr.nextLine();` to `scnr.next();`

Comment: Ah, this code doesn't work. Is that all you can tell us about your issue?

Comment: I had intially been using scnr.next(); as opposed to scnr.nextLine(); but it was cutting off the user input.  I'm getting the following error msg.  Enter a sentence or phrase: The only thing we have to fear is fear itself.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
You entered: The only thing we have to fear is fear itself.

 at textanalyzer.TextAnalyzer.main(TextAnalyzer.java:48)
Number of characters: C:\...\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with calling the wrong things and not matching the format of the method names.  This is what I used.  Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TextAnalyzer {

public static int getNumOfCharacters(String usrText) {
int textLength;

textLength = usrText.length();

return textLength;
}

public static String outputWithoutWhitespace(String usrText) {
String noWhiteSpace = "";

noWhiteSpace = usrText.replaceAll("\\s+","");

return noWhiteSpace;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String usrText = "";


System.out.println("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
usrText = scnr.nextLine();
System.out.println("You entered: " + usrText);

System.out.println();

System.out.print("Number of characters: ");
System.out.println(getNumOfCharacters(usrText));

System.out.print("String with no whitespace: ");
System.out.println(outputWithoutWhitespace(usrText));
return; 
}
}
```

Comment: You really don't need 7 lines of code to return the length of a string. Remove the `getNumOfCharacters()` method altogether.